# Who or what am I - a riddle?

Tags: riddle

> I go round and round but am never tired,
>   Pointing is my job and I am never fired.
>   I have a face and 3 arms but no body.
>   Telling you facts is my hobby.

**What am I?**

Comment: I take it from "apparently", "idk", etc., that this isn't a question you made up but one that someone else asked you -- could you tell us a bit about where it comes from, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You're a clock!
> Your hands go round and round, but, being a machine, you never tire. Your hands point to the numbers. You have a clock face and you have an hour, minute, and second hand. Because you're a clock, you don't have a body. Finally, clocks tell the time, a fact.

Edit: Since you're not that (as stated in the comments), could you be a...

> Watch? That would even better fulfill the 'no body' requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  Congratulations on your first answer.  There is a convention here that we put our answers into spoilers (start the line with `>!`) so that they aren't immediately seen by others who might want to solve the puzzle themselves.

Comment: That's what my thought but apparently a clock is not the answer. And Idk what else.